# Is there a way to show different source feeds on individual pages?

Tags: import, custom-content

As a freelance writer, I have a few outlets I write for routinely plus additional sites, and while I used to post my content manually, due to SEO concerns and logistical issues, I have been looking to modify my Wordpress install to pull posts of mine from my client websites and display the content as it is added.

I'm not sure if this is a valid comparison, but essentially I want to use Wordpress like Mahara which seems to be built for you to post all types of content, like a digital potfolo, all in one place.

Although I did try Mahara (http://demo.mahara.org/) for a short period, I ultimately went back to Wordpress because of the community and also the fact I'm used to using it for client projects and such.

Thanks in advance for any assistance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to your title cuz' i couldnt
understand the question in your explenation ;)

**Sure... no need to even work hard.

Here you can find an easy way to

do exatly that with ready designs:**

- [feed2js.org](http://feed2js.org/index.php?s=build)

Hope This helps,
Sagive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definately helps a lot and I love the simplicity!